# SwiftUI - How to animate (maxHeight: .infinity)?

Tags: animation, swiftui, frame

I simplified my code into the example below.

After the view above has animated, its size changed. How can I apply animation to the frame of the view below?

```
VStack {
    View1()
    
    View2()
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
}

struct View1: View {
    @State private var animate = false
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(animate ? 100 : 200)
            .onTapGesture {
                animate.toggle()
            }
            .animation(.easeInOut, value: animate)
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.red
    }
}
```

I tried this, it works. But everything else inside View2 would also animate, which is not what I want.

```
View2()
    .animation(.easeInOut)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

- you have two views in a `VStack`
- when the top view gets smaller, you want the bottom view to fill the space, with animation
- the content of the bottom view should not be over-animated.

I think it is actually the `VStack` where you need to focus on. A VStack actually animates changes to its contents anyway, so it is enough if you use `withAnimation` to toggle the flag, instead of an explicit `.animation` modifier.

I think this works as you were wanting:

```swift
struct View1: View {
    @State private var animate = false
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: animate ? 100 : 200, height: animate ? 100 : 200)
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation {
                    animate.toggle()
                }
            }
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.red
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            View1()

            View2()
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
        }
    }
}
```

So in summary, use `withAnimation` instead of `.animation()`.

Comment: Great! In fact, another solution might be to add ```.animation(.none, value: animate)``` to the top-level view inside View2, so that animation does not extend to the contents of the container. However, this would mean the flag would have to be passed in to both views as a ```Binding```.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `.transaction` modifier.

```
View2()
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
        .transaction { transform in
          transform.animation = .easeInOut
        }
```

Comment: This modifier seems to apply animation to everything else inside View2()

Comment: Yes, it would modify View2 as a whole. If you have one element inside View2 that dictates the entire frame (like a shape or color), then applying the transaction modifier to just to that element is another possibility.